# IE7-like Quick tab with WPF

Tags: wpf, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to create a IE7-like Quick tab (the tab that displays a thumbnail image of all opended tab) using WPF. How can I render the content of the tab items into images?

Thanks,
Shahaf.

Answer (score 2):

You can use VisualBrush in WPF to do that
check out this link
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFImageEffects.aspx

Comment: Already tried that approach. It works fine for the active tab, but not for the rest of them. When I tried to render a tab item different then the current one I got nothing (empty image).

Any other ideas?